# why `ifconfig` shows 3 eth interfaces, while router has four

Tags: linux, networking, router, ifconfig

My router (Netgear r6700) has four ethernet ports.
I telnet to it, and run `ifconfig`:

```
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <mac address>
          inet addr:192.168.1.1  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          <a lot of other stuff>
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <mac_address>
          <a lot of other stuff>
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <mac_address>
          <a lot of other stuff>
eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <mac_address>
          <a lot of other stuff>
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          ...
....
vlan1
vlan2
wl0.1
wl1.1
```

Why there are only `eth0`, `eth1`, `eth2`, but there is no `eth3`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My router (Netgear r6700) has four ethernet ports.

You probably mean it has four Ethernet ports on its ***LAN*** interface.
There's also an Ethernet port on its WAN interface.
And since this is a dual-band WiFi router, there are also two IEEE802.11 wireless interfaces.

> I telnet to it, and run `ifconfig`:

You should try `ifconfig -a` to obtain a complete listing of network interfaces.

> Why there are only `eth0`, `eth1`, `eth2`, but there is no `eth3`?

You misunderstand the information you have.
The `ethx` (and `br0`) network interfaces refer to Ethernet [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_access_control) controllers, and not to the Ethernet LAN ports.

An Ethernet jack (i.e. the visible *"port'*) is 1-to-1 with a dedicated [PHY chip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHY).
One or more PHYs can connect to a MAC over a [MMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media-independent_interface) or RMMI bus.
It is the MAC that users think of as the Ethernet controller or interface.
But an Ethernet controller can handle more than one PHY or port/jack.

In other words, Ethernet interfaces are not necessarily mapped one-to-one with Ethernet ports.

---

The *"HWaddr <mac_address>"* that you redacted could provide some clarity as to the MAC-to-PHY connections.
Each Ethernet MAC has an address, i.e. its MAC address, which is exposed to the local network.
Whereas the PHY address is only used on the (internal) MII/RMII bus.
Try issuing the command `arp 192.168.1.1` from a PC connected to LAN port 0, then connected to LAN port 1, then connected to LAN port 2, and then connected to LAN port 3.
Compare the reported `HWaddress` from the `arp` commands to the MAC addresses of your WiFi router.

Comment: thanks @sawdust. I realize, my knowledge is such limited, that I make many wrong assumptions when asking a question. Thanks for shedding light to eth interface vs PHY vs eth port, very helpful

Comment: You're welcome.  I hope you will post a report on the MAC addresses from the suggested test.